# "Could not find or load main class" - Jar creation questions

Tags: java, windows, jar, executable-jar

I've been looking at other answers on here, but I just don't get it. Here's what I have:

C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Java\Project\Application.java

I compile that file using this command `javac *.java -d Output -encoding utf-8`
Which compiles into

C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Java\Project\Output\Application.class

Afterwards I use this command to make a jar file `jar cvfmn ..\build\Application.jar ..\MANIFEST Application.class`
(This is run from within the Output folder, and yes there is a manifest file in the project directory.) When I try to run the file I get this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\scuba\Documents\Java\Project\build\Application.jar`

I've attempted to create a manifest file, but I have no idea how to, and my changes never seem to affect it.
All I need is a jar file I can just double-click and run from Windows. And yes, I know I can do `java -jar Application.jar` but that requires the command line, and is not something I can give to another user without expecting them to remember that every time.

Inside the Application.java file, there is essentially this:

```
class Application {
    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
        //my dumb code
    }
}
```

I think all I need, is an explanation as to what needs to be in my manifest file. As I said I've seen other questions like this, but all the answers say something about a package, and afaik I don't have a 'package'. I started Java coding a few days ago so I don't understand all the terminology yet. I'm still used to C based languages.

Comment: [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) `Main-Class: exampleClass` Note that you should rename `Application.java` to `exampleClass`, or `exampleClass` should be named `Application`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In my actual code the class and filename are the same, I didn't know if that was necessary so to make my post easier to understand I changed them. I'll edit the post now, thanks.

Oh yeah, and I have tried setting `Main-Class: Application` so I guess my problem is something else.